Why is the Authorization header preferred for JWTs over HttpOnly cookies in API authentication?
When implementing API authentication using JWTs, most standards (like OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect) recommend placing the token in the Authorization header, using the Bearer scheme
However, I’m wondering why this is preferred over using HttpOnly cookies, which seem to offer better security. HttpOnly cookies have the following advantages:

They cannot be accessed via JavaScript, reducing the risk of XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks.

They are automatically included in requests to the server, simplifying client-side implementation.


Given these benefits, what are the technical or practical reasons for preferring the Authorization header for JWTs
I implemented API authentication by placing the JWT in the Authorization header as per standard practice. However, since the browser does not automatically add the token to the header, it becomes the client’s responsibility to explicitly include it in every request. This led to challenges in consistently managing token inclusion across various API calls in a browser-based environment.
